# BroadCastReceiver for new Image in Android (Xamarin)

Tags: java, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

at the moment I am trying to implement an auto photo upload service with Xamarin.Android.

My problem is that the BroadCastReceiver that is responsible for starting the service does not get called. Here is what I have so far:

**AutoUploadBroadCastReceiver**:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[]{global::Android.Hardware.Camera.ActionNewPicture, global::Android.Hardware.Camera.ActionNewVideo, Intent.ActionCameraButton}, Priority = int.MaxValue, DataMimeType = "image/jpg")]
public class AutoUploadBroadCastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        /* this does not get called */
        var serviceIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(AutoUploadService));
        serviceIntent.PutExtras(intent);
        context.StartService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

**AutoUploadService**:

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { global::Android.Hardware.Camera.ActionNewPicture, global::Android.Hardware.Camera.ActionNewVideo, Intent.ActionCameraButton}, Priority = int.MaxValue, DataMimeType = "image/jpg")]
public class AutoUploadService : Service
{
       /* implementation of service -- working (tested) */
}
```

Additionally here is the auto-generated **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
 <!-- ... -->
 <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="boxcryptor.ui.android.worker.AutoUploadBroadCastReceiver">
  <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
    <action android:name="android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE" />
    <action android:name="android.hardware.action.NEW_VIDEO" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/jpg" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name="boxcryptor.ui.android.worker.AutoUploadService">
  <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
    <action android:name="android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE" />
    <action android:name="android.hardware.action.NEW_VIDEO" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/jpg" />
  </intent-filter>
</service>
 <!-- ... -->
```

Android shows that my service is running, but the broadcastreceiver does not get called, when I take a new picture with my phone/tablet (tested on Nexus 4 and Nexus 7).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:***
after Johans' comment I tried this:

> ```
> [IntentFilter(new string[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted }, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.LowPriority)]
> [IntentFilter(new string[] { Camera.ActionNewPicture }, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.LowPriority)]
> [IntentFilter(new string[] { Intent.ActionCameraButton }, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.LowPriority)]
> ```

My manifest also has the permisson android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED.

But my BroadCastReceivers' OnReceive is still not being fired.

I also tested it in Relase mode (instead of Debug).

**Edit 2:***

This finally works (but only when the application is already running and the user takes a picture):

```
    [BroadcastReceiver]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { global::Android.Content.Intent.ActionBootCompleted }, Categories = new string[] { "android.intent.category.DEFAULT" })]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { Camera.ActionNewPicture }, Categories = new string[] { "android.intent.category.DEFAULT" }, DataMimeType = "image/*")]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { Intent.ActionCameraButton }, Categories = new string[] { "android.intent.category.DEFAULT" })]
public class AutoUploadBroadCastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
```

What am I still missing to get the event when the application is not running?

Comment: Are your photos in fact jpeg?  Also I have noticed, it is better to put your intent filters as three different attributes and not like that in one.

Comment: Yes, they are jpg files. I removed the MimeDataType since I don't think it is necessary. I also tried to split up the intent filter (edited question), but it's still not working